# If we have only one replica of the stateful pod, can we use Deployment resource instead of StatefulSet?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-statefulset, kubernetes-deployment

I read a bit about `Deployment` vs `StatefulSet` in Kubernetes. We usually need `StatefulSet` when we have a stateful app, so every pod can have its own volume.

Now, I have a task to introduce persistence for `RabbitMq`. I will have only one pod replica of `RabbitMq`. Can I do it with `Deployment`? I don't see any problem with this. That one `RabbitMq` replica will have its own `PersistentVolume`(it will not share volume with other pods since I have only one replica). Also, I would say that if for any reason my `RabbitMq` pod gets restarted, it will continue to read and write from the same storage as before restart.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Its only that they have different behavior if a node becomes unreachable. `Deployment` use at-least-one behavior while `StatefulSet` use at-most-one behavior.

Comment: You'd also have to separately create the PersistentVolumeClaim (a StatefulSet includes a template for one), and for RabbitMQ in particular, manually set the pod's hostname.  There's no particular reason to avoid a StatefulSet if it matches your application, even if you're only going to run 1 replica.

Comment: @DavidMaze The reason why I "avoid" StatefulSet is that we currently don't have persistence and we are currently using Deployment. So, I suggested switching to StatefulSet, and then one developer asked me: "Well if we only have one replica, can't we just stick with the Deployment, what is the benefit of the StatefulSet, everything should work with Deployment as well?". And I really don't see why it wouldn't work with Deployment in my specific case. I am not sure what happens when the pod restarts, does it continues to use the same volume that it used before restart or not?

Answer (score 1):

Even with 1 replica, a statefulset still gets you some thing, like stable network ID. You are right that most features stop mattering but it's really up to your specific needs.

Comment: We were not talking about a stable network id(not sure if I need a stable network id in my case). But if we don't need a stable network id, and I have only one replica, do I really need statefulset in order to introduce persistence? What would happen with the persistence of the pods that are managed by deployment if we restart the pod?

Comment: There is no direct difference on persistence with replicas:1. A PVC is a PVC and a PV id a PV, it's literally the same underlying stuff.